# How to assign value from javascript return to razor variable?

Tags: javascript, razor

Here is the example:

```
<script> function getString(){ var a = "something"; return a;} </script>
```

and razor example:

```
string a = "javascript return" or getString();
```

is that possible?

Comment: if this javascript loading off the bat it may be possible to store the javascript variable as a tempData/sessionData, then set your razor variable equal to that (viewbag/tempdata) "on load", but if it does not occur on load then I do not think it is possible as razor turns into regular DOM once it spits out its code.

Comment: This script actually runs on page load, so can you write me a sample of assigning tempData to razor variable?

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to convert JavaScript variable/function call to a Razor variable. *Razor variable is handled by Razor engine on server* where as *JavaScript on the other hand is a client side language running on the client.*

Razor is a view engine used by the ASP.NET MVC framework running on the server to produce some HTML template.

Comment: The point is that i want to take time offset with javascript, and return it to razor, actually i did created script, and also a razor code which takes string as hours, when i hardcode it, works perfectly, javascript also returns what i want as alert, so i wanted to know if i can combine them and get the point. However thank you for your fast response.